# How can I detect two simultaneous touches in Android?

Tags: java, android, touch-event, motionevent

Hi I've been scouring Stackoverflow and reading Android documentation and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I want to detect a second press and perform a different action. Am I limited by the version of Android I'm trying to code into? I was wanting it to be universal so am using 2.3 right now.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if ((event.getY() > (getHeight() - 300)) && event.getX() < 200){
            //Perform Task
        }
        if ((event.getY() > (getHeight() - 300)) && 200 < event.getX() && event.getX() < 400){
            //Perform Task2
        }
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
        if (event.getY(2) > (getHeight()-300) && event.getX(2) > getWidth()-400){
            //Perform Combo Task
        }
    }
```

Above is a small excerpt from my project where I think the problem is originating. I've tried moving the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN inside the if statement with no change in results. What am I doing wrong? I can't even figure out how to properly test it. This is also my first full app I'm making, so I am still very much a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One call to the `onTouch` method is **one** touch. Are you trying to use multitouch? Like 2 fingers on the screen? If so, have a look at the guidelines: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html